# Can I ignore Eclipse serialversionuid missing warning for SOME parts of my project?

Tags: eclipse

So some autogenerated code generates all these [does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/eclipse-ignore-serialversionuid-warning/) warnings.

Is there a way to make Eclipse ignore this for just part of a project (a folder and children), as we otherwise do want the warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if it's a separate source folder configured in the project. Open the project Properties and go to the **Java Build Path** section, find the source folder in question. A picture is worth a thousand words here; this shows the `generated` source folder has optional compile markers ignored:

[image]